# What are valid (and invalid) characters for Avro Schema namespaces

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I have an Avro schema with a namespace of "ca.gms.api-event-log".  I have used this schema to serialize messages into Kafka, successfully registered that schema with the Kafka Schema Registry and am using a Kafka Connector to send that data to Amazon S3 as .avro files.  So far, no issues.

I am now attempting to copy that data from AWS S3 to Azure using Azure Data Factory, and it's complaining about the following:

Failed to deserialize Avro source file 'topics/api-event-log/partition=0/api-event-log+0+0000000000.avro'. This could be caused by invalid Avro data. Check the data and try again. Namespace 'ca.gms.api-event-log' contains invalid characters. . Activity ID: 12a7dda0-8cb7-4c79-a070-d366fddb1c00

Does "ca.gms.api-event-log" really contain invalid characters?  Are hyphens not allowed?  The Apache Avro spec seems to indicate any valid JSON string should work: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that hyphens are not allowed in the Python avro client, but are fine in the Java API.

Therefore, it ultimately depends on the parser being used, but I'd say that the rule of thumb is keep the same naming rules of Java packages, where hyphens also aren't allowed.

Note: You should probably try using a Kafka Connector capable of writing to Azure rather than paying S3 storage + transfer fees. Also not clear why files are even being opened to check schemas if you are just copying raw files